# How to access this variable from an Android onCreate method?

Tags: android, android-activity, global-variables

The problem is that I can't access the userId variable value from inside the onCreate method. I'm accessing the activity from two different activities so I have to check from which one I'm coming from, I do that with the caller but the value returned by the getDetailsUserId method is 0 all the time even though userId is a class variable.

If I initialize userId with 5 for example that's the value returned by the getDetailsUserId method... not the value from the onCreate method.

```
public class Details extends Activity {

    long userId;

    long getDetailsUserId(){
        return userId; //This is the variable value I can't get.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final String caller;

        //Get previous activity name
        caller = getIntent().getStringExtra("com.mysite.myapp.Caller");

        //Get user id from "List"
        if(caller.equals("List")){
            List userListId = new List();
            userId = userListId.getUserListId();
        }

        //Get user id from "Profile Saved"
        else if(caller.equals("ProfileSaved")){
            ProfileSaved savedUserId = new ProfileSaved();
            userId = savedUserId.getSavedUserId();
        }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure userListId.getUserListId() doesn't return 0 always?

Comment: getDetailsUserId() is useless in this code. Just refer to userId since it is a class instance variable.

Comment: Yes I,m sure because the database is working. The problem is just the value of the variable.

Comment: Lazy Ninja getDetailsUserId() is not useless, I'm using it as an accessor for another activity.

Comment: Also note that you are setting userId only if caller is "List" or "ProfileSaved". There is no else part of the if loop. So, it is quite possible that caller is not equal to "List" or "ProfileSaved" and thus userId is never set. Check that part, maybe by logging that the if loops are entered.

Comment: @user1813774 : Don't share data between two activities like this - you're in for a lot of pain. Learn about the Activity Lifecycle - the Android `Activity` class is a special case. When one `Activity` is visible the other will either be paused, stopped or destroyed. Learn to use `SharedPreferences` or use a helper class.

Comment: omermuhammed Ok, the values should never be different but I'll check that.

Comment: Sorry, but you need a separate method for accessing the instance variable value with a method. You can directly access its value isn't it?. If you want to access the variable outside the activity

Comment: @user1813774 Thanks I'll check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, changed my previous answer. Tried it and it worked for me.

Here it is

```
public static class Details extends Activity {

   static long userId;

    long getDetailsUserId(){
        return userId; //This is the variable value I can't get.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final String caller;

        //Get previous activity name
        caller = getIntent().getStringExtra("com.mysite.myapp.Caller");

        //Get user id from "List"
        if(caller.equals("List")){
            List userListId = new List();
            userId = userListId.getUserListId();
        }

        //Get user id from "Profile Saved"
        else if(caller.equals("ProfileSaved")){
            ProfileSaved savedUserId = new ProfileSaved();
            this.userId = savedUserId.getSavedUserId();
        }

}

}
```

Comment: misterdev Thanks! I'm making a new object instead, but the word `static` made the whole difference, after many hours it works :)

Comment: @shoriwa-shaun-benjamin get you reputation back. Here is my like.

Comment: You can make an Activity static ?