# Android - Get variable from oncreate() of another class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, oncreate

I have a class *GetMyLocation* that gets the current location of the user. Now I'm trying to call an object of this class from another class, *ShowMap2*. But I am unable to send the updated location to the new class.

I haven't included the other overrides for GetMyLocation here.

What I have:

```
public class ShowMap2 extends Activity{
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_showmap);

        GetMyLocation myLocation = new GetMyLocation();


        myLat = myLocation.GetCurrentLat();
        myLon = myLocation.GetCurrentLon();

   }
```

This is the class that gets the location:

```
public class GetMyLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {


    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    Location location;

    public static double myLat, myLon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


       this.myLat = location.getLatitude();
       this.myLon = location.getLongitude();

    }


    public double GetCurrentLat(){
        return this.myLat;
    }

    public double GetCurrentLon(){
        return this.myLon;
    }
```

The above code returns 0.0 for both lat and lon.

I have tried every possible way I could think of, but I always end up get 0.0. I know the class itself gets my current lat and lon, but I am not able to pass it correctly. Could some please help me out here?

Thanks.

PS:

I found this thread, and tried it accordingly, but to no avail. Still zeros.

[How to access this variable from an Android onCreate method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947353/how-to-access-this-variable-from-an-android-oncreate-method)

The only difference, in the question in the link, the class is static. When I make my class static, it says: Modifier 'static' not allowed here.

My updated code:

```
public class GetMyLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    Location location;

    static double myLat, myLon;

    double GetCurrentLat(){
        return myLat;
    }

    double GetCurrentLon(){
        return myLon;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        this.myLat = location.getLongitude();
        this.myLon = location.getLongitude();

    }
```

EDIT: Updated Code that works:

```
public class GetMyLocation implements LocationListener {
//public class GetMyLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    private static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(43.48484521,-80.5274279);
    private GoogleMap map;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    Location location;

    private static double myLat, myLon;

    GetMyLocation(Activity activity){

        locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        this.myLat = location.getLatitude();
        this.myLon = location.getLongitude();

    }

    double GetCurrentLat(){
        return this.myLat;
    }

    double GetCurrentLon(){
        return this.myLon;
    }
```

getting the location values from ShowMap2 using:

```
GetMyLocation myLocation = new GetMyLocation(this);
```

Comment: did u send the variables via intent in secondActivity?

Comment: simply instantiation a class `GetMyLocation myLocation = new GetMyLocation();` does not call methods on it `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);'  You need to learn how to create a new Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're extending `Activity` in `GetMyLocation`. For the goal you want, remove `extends Activity`, and move the code from `onCreate()` to a suitable constructor such as `GetMyLocation()`.

The rest of your logic is solid.

An activity is for GUI, and if you don't intend on opening a new activity with your class, don't extend `Activity`. For the code to work from `onCreate()`, you'd have to create an intent of your class, and start the activity, which would open a blank activity, because you're not setting any views in `GetMyLocation`.

In layman's terms, your `onCreate()` is never called because you're never starting the activity.

**EDIT** To pass a `Context` to our class so it runs correctly, we will define our constructor like so:

```
GetMyLocation(Context context) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    this.myLat = location.getLatitude();
    this.myLon = location.getLongitude();

}
```

And we will initialize our class like so: `GetMyLocation location = new GetMyLocation(this);` from within your `Activity`. When we reference `this` from our class, it points to that class, which just so happens to be an `Activity` satisfying our `GetMyLocation(Context context)` constructor. Then you can call your methods and get the expected results.

When you originally called `getSystemService()` you implied `this` which was a reference to your activity that was never started. That's also why your IDE got mad at you when you removed `extends Activity` from `GetMyLocation()`. It didn't know where to look for for `getSystemService()`, because the implied class `this` was no longer a `Context`.

Comment: If I remove extend Activity, it cannot resolve getSystemService.

Also I had previously moved the code from onCreate() to a contructor. But that would make the app close/crash when I ran it.

Comment: Then you must pass a `Context` as a parameter in your constructor. I'll add an example snippet to my answer.

Comment: That works well, thanks. Just one question, what is the Context that I should be passing from my ShowMap2 class. This is my first app in Java, so I'm sort of lost.

Comment: @fractal5, `Context` is what `Activity` extends, and `getSystemService()` is a method of `Context`. You can replace `Context` with `Activity` and in your instance, it will run exactly the same with no errors. Every `Activity` is a `Context`, but every `Context` is not an `Activity`. Just like every cat is an animal, but every animal is not a cat. If this concept doesn't make sense, google java inheritance and take a look at some of the documentation. Oh and if you feel I've helped you feel free to upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: @fractal5, also think of animals eating. All animals eat, but not every animal necessarily eats the same thing, or the same way. This is akin to inherited methods.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has really helped. I'll look up context and inheritance and hopefully it solves the issue. Unfortunately I cannot vote up, since I don't have 15 reps. Answer Accepted!

Comment: The little check mark to the left of my answer ;). Hey, no problem. The point of this site is we've ALL been there. We're here to help. I'd also like to note, the only reason `Activity` will work instead of `Context` is because your `Context` is an `Activity`. Switch that, with, say a `Service ` and it won't work.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a ton!

Updated code posted in original question for future references.

Comment: @fractal5, very nice. Might I suggest implementing a `refreshLocation()` method in your `GetMyLocation` class. The method could simply call `location = getLastKnownLocation(..);` as you do, but then subsequent calls to `GetCurrentLon()` and `GetCurrentLat()` will reflect the most recent location. Also are you aware that you're setting both `myLat` AND `myLon` BOTH to `location.getLongitude()`?

Comment: Hahaha I noticed that after ending up in Antartica a bunch of times. I think there is a method like refreshLocation method, however I had disabled it initially while debugging the app. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass parameters from Activity to Activity, use Bundle. 
If you want to get result when Activity is exiting, use startActivityForRestult when creating the new Activity.
If you just want to pass parameters from Activity to another class, use the class's constructor.